# Is `device_idle_constants` deprecated in Android 12?

Tags: settings, terminal, android-12, doze-mode

Recently I've been trying to optimize the doze settings for my device. I found many guides that date back to 2015/16. All of them say something similar: To change a `deviceidle` setting, I have to input `adb shell settings put global device_idle_constants inactive_to=30000,sensing_to=0` (for example) in a terminal. When typing in `adb shell settings list global`, `device_idle_constants` doesn't get listed tho. Seems to me it's deprecated.

**My Problem:** This setting doesn't change anything at all. When I change `sensing_to` to 0 like I have shown above, it's still at `4m0s0ms`. I can confirm this by putting `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle` in the terminal.

Does anyone know how to change those doze parameters in Android 12(L)?

Btw: I have a Poco F3 with LineageOS 19.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Doze configuration has been moved from global system settings until Android 11 to device configuration since Android 12.**

Until Android 11, [the Doze configuration is in `Settings.Global` with `device_idle_constants` as the key](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android11-release:frameworks/base/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java;l=11461), thus it's still possible to change the configuration using `adb shell settings put global device_idle_constants [VALUE]`, with `[VALUE]` as a single string, separated with comma for multiple values.

However, since Android 12, [the flags have been migrated to `DeviceConfig` with `device_idle` as the namespace](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/1e55861ed47de9be04537c6df64f2dbf4ef868cd). To change the configuration, use `adb shell device_config put device_idle [KEY] [VALUE]` instead.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I wanted to thank you for this. Still using this to tweak idle drain for my Android phone.
I've also written a guide on xda for this and mentioned your answer there. If you want to check it out, here it is: https://xdaforums.com/t/improve-idle-drain-by-tweaking-android-doze-parameters.4479005/